# Homemade plugin while using Themify Ultra

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, themes

I am using the theme called Themify Ultra for a webproject. [Theme can be found here](https://themify.me/themes/ultra).

I want to make a plugin that changed letters to other letters like leetspeak. Here is the code in my plugin that is located in the plugin folder.

```
<?php

/*
    Plugin name: information
    Description: Lägga till den nödvändiga informationen

*/


        function info_change_content($content){
            
            $content = str_ireplace("s", "5", $content);
            $content = str_ireplace("l", "1"
    
    , $content);
        $content = str_ireplace("t", "7", $content);
        $content = str_ireplace("o", "0", $content);
        $content = str_ireplace("ck", "XX", $content);
        
        return $content;
        
        }
        
        add_filter("the_content", "info_change_content");
```

I have activated the plugin but it wont change the letters. Has this something with the theme to do? Can't I do this while using this theme?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where do you expect to see the changes? the plugin will only change the text within the content of posts or pages... if you suspect your theme, try to switch to one of the default themes like Twenty Seventeen and test again.